# Can I flatten/unpack the property during serialization to JSON?

Tags: json, asp.net-core

I have following types:

```
class A{ 
  public int A{get;set;}
  public int B{get;set;}
}

class B{
 public A A {get; set;}
 public int C {get;set;}
}
```

is there an annotation which I could use for `public A A{get;set;}` which would cause flattening/unpacking contents of the `A` so the output JSON returned by the API endpoint would look like:

```
{
"a" : valuea,
"b" : valueb,
"c" : valuec
}
```

instead of

```
{
 "a": {"a": valuea, "b": valueb},
 "c": valuec
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write a custom [JsonConverter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/converters-how-to?pivots=dotnet-7-0#registration-sample---jsonconverter-on-a-property) for the property.

Or, a more hacky solution:

```
class A{ 
  public int A{get;set;}
  public int B{get;set;}
}

class B
{
 [JsonIgnore]
 public A ClassA {get; set;}
 [JsonProperty]
 int A => ClassA.A;
 [JsonProperty]
 int B => ClassA.B;
 public int C {get;set;}
}
```

This will cause serializer to ignore the Class A property, but include the private properties A and B which will get the values from Class A.